# May I modify the code/program for my undergraduate thesis project?

Tags: research-undergraduate, online-resource, code

I have a project for undergraduate thesis. Then, I found this [Chapter VBI-6.   Hand and Finger Detection](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui055/). In the Downloads section, there's code that we can download and launched. I want to use it and have to modify or tweak it to suit my project. The problem is that, I don't know whether it's allowed or not to make a modification to the code presented. Inside, I found this sentences:

> If you use this code, please mention my name, and include a link
>   to the website.

By "use", may I tweak the code as long as I refer to the coder? I'm confused because I found nothing about its license inside the code, like, GNU-GPL or MIT...

I'm so sorry if my question is wrong. If so, please tell why and maybe where I can ask it.

Comment: That is an ambiguous enough statement from the author about licensing, that I would simply send them an email and ask what they would allow. I would also ask your advisor if this kind of work is acceptable for your project. If the project requires more self-work, you need to know that before you use too much of this code. Finally, if you use it, don't forget to cite it.

Comment: I'm conflicted about sending the author for a permission, because, I'm not even sure whether I would really use it. Though, at this point, his code is the one most suitable. And I'm afraid if he wants to see my implementation, it would only gave him cancer... Citation surely will be given.

Comment: @zargin getting _permission_ to modify and redistribute the code does not _require_ you to do so. You have nothing to lose by asking. (Alternatively if your advisor is okay with you using it, you could tweak the code, see if it does what you need it to do, and then only ask for permission when you're confident you will want to share your modified code with the world.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an ambiguous enough statement from the author about licensing, that I would simply send them an email and ask what they would allow. You can make your decision on whether to use it after you know whether you can.

I would also ask your advisor if this kind of work is acceptable for your project. If the project requires more self-work, you need to know that before you use too much of this code.

Finally, if you do use it, don't forget to cite it.

Comment: Thanks Sir, seems that the only way... Naaa, actually, my thesis focus on 'Design', but I have to make a demo to test it, so that's why I search for a complete code like that.